# Pip Deps Issue when bazel build on target - "KeyError: Torch"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, bazel

I've cloned a repo from my company, and I'm trying to get a target built and deployed using bazel. The repo has a giant requirements.txt, and I `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` in a virtualenv. Things seem to have been installed correctly with no issue.

Now, I'm trying to build a bazel target, and I'm getting a lot of errors. See full error here: https://pastebin.com/raw/XHct8SsX (I've omitted some of the packages installed)

To mention a few that I'm seeing:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'pip_deps':
   rules_python_external failed: Collecting https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz (from -r /home/vagrant/path/to/requirements.txt (line 127))
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz (13.7 MB)
```

and

```
...
Collecting torch==1.7.1
  Downloading torch-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (776.8 MB)
 (ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'torch'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/commands/wheel.py", line 159, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=True
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 82, in from_requirement
    if not cands:
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 124, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 38, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 169, in _make_candidate_from_link
    name=name, version=version,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 306, in __init__
    version=version,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 312, in _prepare_distribution
    self._ireq, parallel_builds=True,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 457, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    self.download_dir, hashes,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 234, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 108, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 163, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 88, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 65, in read
    self._close()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 52, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 309, in cache_response
    cache_url, self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 72, in dumps
    return b",".join([b"cc=4", msgpack.dumps(data, use_bin_type=True)])
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 960, in pack
    self._pack(obj)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 944, in _pack
    len(obj), dict_iteritems(obj), nest_limit - 1
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 1045, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 944, in _pack
    len(obj), dict_iteritems(obj), nest_limit - 1
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 1045, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/pypi__pip/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 889, in _pack
    return self._buffer.write(obj)
MemoryError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/rules_python/python/pip_install/extract_wheels/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/19b3288ab9313c25fda35a5d8cf325eb/external/rules_python/python/pip_install/extract_wheels/__init__.py", line 87, in main
    subprocess.run(pip_args, check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--isolated', 'wheel', '-r', '/home/vagrant/path/to/requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
)
```

Versioning Info:

- Python 3.7.5
- pip 21.1.2 from /home/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue - I had to increase memory to Vagrant from 2gb to 4gb. It at least stopped crashing at that point, but instead the whole VM crashed since my computer ran out of disk space. Not sure what bazel is doing here...